# PNG to XPS converter Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, png, xps, converters

Does anybody know how to convert PNG to XPS on Ubuntu through the console? I found a lot of info on the internet about how to convert XPS to other formats but as usual, all these libs don't support convert from other formats to XPS.

I saw that GhostScript has XPS plugin but I didn't find how to install it?

So can someone help me with it or maybe you know any way how to do it in PHP?

Thanks.

PS: I try to convert .pdf and .ps files like

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=xpswrite -sOutputFile=output.xps input.ps
```

but it always creates xps with one page which empty and has a white background. Maybe it possible to correct my gs command.

Comment: have you tried `convert`?

Comment: Yes but it tells me that can't do this :(